# Purpose of casting a struct pointer to void without using the result

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

I am trying to make sense of the following bit of C code.

```
static unsigned
parent(const struct binheap *bh, unsigned u)
{
    (void)bh;
    return (u / 2);
}
```

What could the purpose of `(void)bh;` be? It is not assigned to anything and should not have an effect on the output. The only purpose I can think of might be as a kind of an assert against a null pointer perhaps.

For context, that snippet is from [the original implementation](https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/blob/master/lib/libvarnish/binary_heap.c#L163) of a [B-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-heap). That code tends to be rather too clever in other places as well, e.g. doing `for (unsigned n = 2; n; n += n) {` to break at n = 65536.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(void)bh;` has no effect *in the generated code*.  However, with many compilers it will prevent the compiler from issuing a warning about the parameter `bh` not being otherwise used in the function, and that was almost certainly the intent of the programmer.  `bh` being a struct pointer is irrelevant; if this technique works at all, it will work regardless of the type of the unused parameter.

C++ has a more elegant way to accomplish this, allowing you to omit the variable name for any argument you don't need --

```
static unsigned
parent(const struct binheap *, unsigned u)
{
     return (u / 2);
}
```

-- but C doesn't support this.  Some compilers have extensions for the same purpose that are, if not so elegant, at least more self-describing,  e.g. GCC's

```
static unsigned
parent(const struct binheap *bh __attribute__((unused)), unsigned u)
{
     return (u / 2);
}
```

The `(void)bh;` trick is the only technique for suppressing unused-parameter warnings that uses only the facilities of ISO C; on the other hand, it's not guaranteed to work, the warnings a compiler emits are entirely up to that compiler, so you're already in implementation-defined territory no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done to **avoid compiler warnings**. For example, if compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` in `gcc`, it will warn you that you're not using `bh` IF you do not make the cast to void.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply to avoid the compiler warning against an unused variable. Without the cast there in place, you compiler will (*try to*) warn you that you have an unused variable in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Because **compiler warning**

Some compilers throw warning when a variable is unused within the function. See below

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(int a, int b)
{
  int i = b + 1;
   printf("hello %d\n", i);
  return;
}

int main(void)
{
 hello(10, 20);
 return 0;
}
```

Compiling it as below to see the warning

```
$ gcc -Wunused-parameter a.c                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
a.c:3:16: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
void hello(int a, int b)
               ^
1 warning generated.
```